# how to load spinner from selected item of autoComplete textview hashmap from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I make AutoCompleteTextView of keys (car brands) that get from `HashMap`, I want to load values of selected brand (car model) to spinner, spinner is load car model of the last item only not to selected one.

[here is  response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPCoe.png)

```
AutoCompleteTextView actBrand;
Spinner spinnerModel;
ArrayList<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterBrands;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterModel;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList>> mapArrayList;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList>> mapValueArrayList;
String keys;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actBrand = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBrand);
    spinnerModel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerModel);

    getdata();
}

 public void getdata() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("carBrands");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated
            mapArrayList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();


            //get data from Firebase 

            for (HashMap<String, ArrayList> hash : mapArrayList) {
                // For each hashmap, iterate over it
                for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList> entry : hash.entrySet()) {

                    keys = entry.getKey();
                    keyList.add(keys);
                    hash.keySet();
                    valueList = entry.getValue();
                    valueList = hash.get(keys);

                }
            }
        }
         @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("tag", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });

    arrayAdapterBrands =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, keyList);
    actBrand.setAdapter(arrayAdapterBrands);

    actBrand.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

selected item of keys in AutoComplete Textview

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Log.v("getListSelection", String.valueOf(item));
```

here i want to load specific list depend on key selected

```
            arrayAdapterModel =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valueList);
            spinnerModel.setAdapter(arrayAdapterModel);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error? What is going on with this code?

Comment: @AlexMamo 
 there is no error

Comment: @PeterHaddad no , can't solve the problem yet